# UITextField screws up after adding dots / decimals

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have my UITextField with an UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad as keyboard, so that users only can input integers. Now in order to make their input a bit more readable, I decided to add the following code:

```
formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
self.inputField.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:[formatter numberFromString:self.inputField.text]];
```

in order to change 1234 in 1,234 and so on

this works, up till the first decimal. If i comment this code out, I can put in values up till 999999999 and further if I want, but if I add this code, my text input goes like this

1 stays the same
12 stays the same
123 stays the same
1234 becomes 1,234
if i then enter an extra number (5 for example), it clears my UITextField instead of making it 12,345

how can I prevent this?

Comment: When you are changing from 1,234 to 12,345 are you editing the text or completely re-entering it? It could be because the comma is part of the UITextField's text and therefore not a correctly formatted number, which would clear it.

Comment: I just tried with changing the keyboard to Default, which should accept everything, and same problem occurs.

Comment: Try removing all of the commas from the text before applying numberFromString.

Comment: @NicRobertson Don't assume commas. Many countries use other symbols such as periods or spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the text field has `1,234` and the user enters a `5` you end up with `1,2345` in the text field. Correct?

You then attempt to convert that string to a number using the formatter. But that's not a valid number. This is why the result becomes blank.

What you need to do is take the current text field value and strip any thousands separators and then reformat the result.

```
formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSString *separator = [formatter groupingSeparator];
// Remove any existing grouping separators from the text field text
NSString *current = self.inputField.text;
current = [current stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:separator withString:@""];
// Reformat the number
self.inputField.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:@([current integerValue])];
```

Comment: had to change the last line ( self.inputField.text = current ) but works perfectly then :) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Well thats because `1,2345` is a not correctly formatted decimal number and you try to recognize it as a number. You should use instead:

```
NSNumberFormatter *decimalFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[decimalFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

NSString *onlyNumbers = [[self.inputField.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

self.inputField.text = [decimalFormatter stringFromNumber:[numberFormatter numberFromString:onlyNumbers]];
```

Comment: looks like the same answer as above, so I guess this works as well. thanks =)